# How can I insert predefined text in Vim as a command?

Tags: vim

I want to assign values to variables in Vim and paste them where needed with shortcuts.

I know I can assign values to variables using the `let` statement:

```
:let foo="bar"
```

How can I insert its value in my text, for instance, like this?

```
:inoremap <F5> :insertContentsOf(foo)
```

Answer (score 3):

You're looking for `i_CTRL-R` (old way), or `:imap-<expr>` (new way, when there is no need to move the cursor nor do fancy things)

```
" Either
inoremap <f5> <c-r>=g:foo<cr>
" Or
inoremap <expr> <f5> g:foo
```

But honestly, you should may be have a look at one of the numerous snippet plugin.